# Transformar json a formato individual de fechas

Tags: javascript, datepicker

Tengo este datepicker ( https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api/):

```
var daysData = <?= json_encode($dataFechas) ?>;
var newA = [];
for( j of daysData){
  let start = moment(j["start"]);
  let end   = moment(j["end"]);
  for (let m = moment(start); m.diff(end, 'days') <= 0; m.add(1, 'days')){
    newA[m.format('YYYY,MM,DD')] = j;
    }
  }

$('#datefilter_inicio, #datefilter_fin').pickadate({    

    // Strings and translations

    disable: [ 
        { from: [2019,1,14], to: [2019,1,27] }
    ],
});
```

En el cual como pueden apreciar deshabilita las fechas que hay dentro de `disable`

La cosa es que tengo un json que le mando al js de este estilo: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que quiero es bloquear todas las fechas de from... to en el disable.

He tratado de pasarle newA al disable, pero todo lo que he intentado no me funciona:

```
disable:[
    var valid = false ; // default css class
    let d =  date.format("DD/MM/YYYY");
    if(typeof newA[d] !== 'undefined'){
        if(newA[d].aceptado == 1 || newA[d].aceptado == 0){
            valid =  true;
        }
      }
      return valid;
    },
    var daySettings = 'day_green';
    let d =  date.format("DD/MM/YYYY");
    if(typeof newA[d] !== 'undefined'){
       daySettings = 'day_red';
       if(newA[d].acept == 0){
        daySettings = 'day_orange';
       }
    }
      return daySettings;
    },
]
```

Gracias por cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Edito: Sugerencia de @Juan

```
let disableArray = [];
    for(dte of daysData){ 
       let date_from = dte.start; 
       let date_to = dte.end;
       console.log(date_from,date_to);
       //let disableFrom = [parseInt(date_from[0]),parseInt(date_from[1]),parseInt(date_from[2])]; 
       //let disableTo = [parseInt(date_to[0]),parseInt(date_to[1]),parseInt(date_to[2])];

       let disableRange = { from: [date_from], to: [date_to] };
       //{ from: [2016,2,14], to: [2016,2,27] }
       //{from: "2018-08-30", to: "2018-08-31"}
       disableArray.push(disableRange);
    }
    console.log(disableArray);
```

Por si ves algo que pueda estar haciendo mal. Creo que es culpa de las "" que no soy capaz de ponerselas sin que lo tome como Array.
El formato que supuestamente necesita es el siguiente:

```
{ from: [2016,2,24], to: [2016,2,27] }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una vez que tenés el array con los from y to:

```
var datearr = [
  {..., "from":"2019-01-01","to":"2019-01-02"},
  {..., "from":"2019-02-10","to":"2019-02-11"},
  {..., "from":"2019-05-01","to":"2019-05-02"}
];
```

podes generar el array (`disableArray`) de disable así:

```
let disableArray = [];
for(let dte of datearr){ 
  let from = dte.from.split("-"); 
  let to = dte.to.split("-");

  let disableFrom = [parseInt(from[0]),parseInt(from[1]) - 1,parseInt(from[2])]; 
  let disableTo = [parseInt(to[0]),parseInt(to[1]) - 1,parseInt(to[2])];

  let disableRange = {"from": disableFrom, "to": disableTo};

  disableArray.push(disableRange);
}
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, lo voy a probar.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Juan, no me da ningún error pero no me bloquea las fechas ya que me devuelve esto el disableArray `0: {from: Array(3), to: Array(3)}` ( y comentarte que tienes un error en la linea de disableRange, te falta un } al final :)